# anyone recognize the font style?

Tags: images, fonts, headers

I have been trying to find the font style/type used in this company's title:

[image]

Anyone recognize it?

Comment: Try http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: There's also: http://www.whatfontis.com/

Comment: Sorry, this is a typography question, this is not computer related.

Answer (score 1):

Try "Compacta Black Poster"

http://screencast.com/t/NDQzZDU3N